# javac : command not found

Tags: java, compilation, centos, javac

I have installed java in my *CentOS release 5.5* machine using the command `yum install java`. But I am unable to compile a class using javac.

Do I need to install any other package?

I have tried to locate the `javac` executable but i am unable to locate it.

`/usr/bin/java` is linked as follows:
`/usr/bin/java` -> `/etc/alternatives/java`
`/etc/alternatives/java` -> `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java`

I have seen the following output by `yum list installed |grep java`:

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64              1:1.6.0.0-1.16.b17.el5          installed
tzdata-java.x86_64                     2011b-1.el5                     installed
```

Comment: It looks like your solution is to use `yum` to `install` `java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You installed the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) only, which [does not provide `javac`](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-appstream-x86_64/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el8_4.x86_64.rpm.html). For `javac`, you have to install the [OpenJDK Development Environment](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-appstream-x86_64/java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el8_4.x86_64.rpm.html). You can install `java-devel` or `java-11-devel`, which both include `javac`.

By the way: you can find out which package provides `javac` with a `yum` search, e.g.

```
su -c 'yum provides javac'
```

on more recent releases of CentOS e.g. 6 the command changes to

```
su -c 'yum provides */javac'
```

Comment: yes, i am sure. just look at the [java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 package information](http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/centos-rhel-updates-x86_64/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.16.b17.el5.x86_64.rpm.html) (scroll to the "Files" section) and see that there is no `javac` in that package. and then look at the [OpenJDK Development Environment package](http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/centos-rhel-updates-x86_64/java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0-1.16.b17.el5.x86_64.rpm.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I have used "yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64"

Comment: On Fedora 20 `yum provides javac` outputs "No matches found".

Comment: but he installed 'openjdk', right?  JDK means java development kit

Comment: If you had an older javac installed, you may need to `sudo alternatives --config javac` to make javac point to the newly installed version.

Answer (score 197):

Worked for me with this command:

```
yum install java-devel
```

Comment: But that installs the obsolete JDK 6. Why doesn't it install JDK 8? "yum install java" does install JRE 8.

Comment: You can grep the output of "yum list" to find the version of java you want, then do "yum install <package>". For me, it was "yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64"

Comment: For java8 use `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

Comment: this should be the answer.

Comment: Other java installs dint provide javac wasted 2 hrs until i stumbled up on this

Answer (score 31):

Use the following sudo command:

```
sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what `yum install java` will actually install. But to check for javac existence do:

```
> updatedb
> locate javac
```

preferably as root. If it's not there you've probably only installed the Java runtime (JRE) and not the Java Development Kit (JDK). You're best off getting this from the [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html): as the Linux repos may be slightly behind with latest versions and also they seem to only supply the open-jdk as opposed to the Oracle/Sun one, which I would prefer given the choice.

Answer (score 2):

Install same version `javac` as your `JRE`

```
yum install java-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Fedora (currently 31)

Even with JDK's installed, I still need to specify JAVAC_HOME in the .bashrc, especially since I have 4 Java versions using sudo alternatives --configure java to switch between them.

To find java location of java selected in alternatives

readlink -f $(which java)

In my case: 
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_241-amd64/jre/bin/java

So I set following in .bashrc to:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_241-amd64/jre/bin/java

export JAVAC_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_241-amd64/bin/javac

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_241-amd64/jre/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_241-amd64/bin/

Now javac –version gives: 
javac 1.8.0_241

This is useful for those who want to use Oracle's version. Just remember to change your .bashrc again if you make a change with java alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
`sudo dnf install java-<version>-devel`

Answer (score 1):

Is the javac executable in a directory that is part of your PATH?

I don't know the CentOS equivalent of the Windows path but if you cd to the java sdk directory and run ./javac does anything happen?

Comment: My problem is where the javac executable will be present by default

Comment: doesn't centos have the locate command? as suggested by @Richard

Comment: I'm sorry, BenCr, I corrected a typo (javajc => javac) but the system only allows to correct at least 6 characters, so I changed something more. On Unix type systems (is CentOS some kind of Unix?) you have to specify ./ to start something in the current directory. Feel free to reedit, if my edits get approved.

Comment: did you accept the wrong answer? if so, please change to the right one so as not to confuse readers.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the Java Runtime Environment(JRE) but it doesn't contain javac.

So on the terminal get access to the root user `sudo -i` and enter the password.
Type `yum install java-devel`, hence it will install packages of javac in fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 19.3

I installed Java Oracle manually, like this:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0_211/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac
```

Answer (score 0):

for java 8 use
***sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel***

Answer (score -2):

### Make sure you install JDK/JRE first.

follow these steps:

open terminal go to your root dictionary by typing

```
cd /
```

you will see Library folder

Now follow this path `Library/Java/JVM/bin`

Once you get into `bin` you can see the `javac` file

Now you need to get the path of this folder for that just write this command

```
pwd
```

get the path for your `javac`.

Comment: The operating system the OP names is CentOS.