# "java" command is getting executed but not "javac" command

Tags: java, javac

My question looks similar to [java-comand-works-but-not-javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565237/java-comand-works-but-not-javac) but its different from the way that I deliberately had removed java bin directory from "path" variable and "JAVA_HOME" so that "java" and "javac" shouldn't be executed without giving full path to "javac" or "java".But still "java" is getting executed. For "javac" it is throwing `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

But for "java" it is showing `C:\Users\Nandi_Gaurav>java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)`

I want to know the reason. I am using "Windows-7" .

Comment: you have jre installed but not [jdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: Install jdk and set your path to it.

Comment: check your `Windows/System32` folder. There is `java.exe` file exist.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov....Thanks for your info. It helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is that `java` running when you don't expect it to<sup>1</sup>, open up a `cmd` window and execute:

```
C:\USERS\Nandi_Gaurav\Documents>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

You'll almost certainly see that there's one installed in the Windows system directory.

That's why it's  still executing even though you *think* you've removed it from the path.

If you *really* want to get rid of it, either delete it (assuming it's still available in the JRE/JDK directory) or rename it to something like `nojava.exe`.

Whatever you do, *don't* remove `c:\windows\system32` from your path, that'll cause all *sorts* of issues :-)

---

<sup>1</sup> Your problem *may* also be that `javac` is not running, in which case the JDK may not be installed. However, based on your question, that doesn't seem to be the issue - you're more concerned about things running when you've tried to disable them, rather than with things not running when they should be.

Comment: you are right ... thanks ..JDK is installed but I had removed the bin folder from "path" variable so "javac" is  throwing error.I wanted to know that why "java" still running even though I had no link to bin folder of JDK and I got my answer .Big Thanks to you

Answer (score 1):

Java may be executed from the JRE that is installed in another path of your system.

Javac is part of the JDK, so you should install it, and set the appropriate paths.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Java Development Kit (JDK) which provides `javac` to compile your java code. You have the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) which is mainly for running java programs.

This question may help: [javac : command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407703/javac-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I think your 'Path'-variable is only used for javac.

Java-configuration in windows can be found here:
[Explanation on java.com](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/win_controlpanel.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Most probable issue could be that you are using JRE instead of JDK.

When you download java you can get it either as jre(Java Runtime Environment) or jdk(Java Development Kit) .

If you just want to  run java programs on a machine , install JRE.

if you want to develop , compile and run a java program install JDK.

Both can be downloaded from oracle.Link for JDK 1.6

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR