# Error in setting up Sublime text 3 to run and compile java on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java, compilation, sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04, sublime-text-plugin

I am new to Sublime Text 3 and I want to run and compile java code on Sublime Text 3.
However, I am getting this weird error:

`/bin/bash: javac: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]`

and my file in `/home/***/Downloads/sublime_text_3/Packages/Java.sublime-package/JavaC.sublime-build`  looks like :

```js
{
   "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java",
}
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit
sublime version: Sublime Text 3.0 build 3143

any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: this is not the weird error it's trying to say that java is not installed or may be java is not set in your current path

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407703/javac-command-not-found

Answer (score 1):

This error says that you have no `javac` installed (which actually is a part of [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)). By default Ubuntu is not bundled with JDK. So you have to install it manually:

```
$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

You can verify that `javac` is present:

```
$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
```

If you see the path to you java compiler everything should work.